# Drawing bitmap fonts from cp-1252 characters

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, cp1252

I'm developping a prototype application to generate bitmap fonts giving TTF.
I'm using Qt library which I'm using for years. However, I realized I've never been involved into "characters"  issues before.

What I'm trying is quiet simple:

I need to draw into a PNG file each character of the 1252 codepage. I'm a bit lost with the different issues related to codec, textdecoder etc.

Any suggestion is welcome !

Z.

Comment: You might take a look at [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/).  That's what we use to generate font textures.

Comment: This link may help: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The codec that you want is `QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1252")`
2. The characters that you want are `char(32)` to `char(255)`; put those in a `char[225]`. Don't forget to zero-terminate them.
3. Convert that `char[225]` to a QString with the codec from (1)
4. Draw the `QString` from (4)